# Synchronizing force:recordData and external JavaScript library on loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, asynchronous

I've got situation in lightning component where on init there should be used data from two sources:

- record loaded via force:recordData
- data from this record parsed with
  use of external JS library methods.

What should be the best practice to synchronize this two things together?

Note that record and external scripts are being loaded asynchronously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you redesign to load synchronously AND do you have control over the when to include the external lib?

If so, there's a callback of sorts in `force:recordData` which you can use to tell the script when to load itself, then parse like this:

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="isRecordLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.isRecordLoaded }">
  <ltng:require scripts="{! $Resource.myResource + '/jsLib.js' }" afterScriptsLoaded="{! c.scriptsLoaded }" />
</aura:if>    

<force:recordData
  ...
  recordUpdated="{! c.handleRecordUpdated }"
  />
```

**Controller**

```
handleRecordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
  let changeType = event.getParams().changeType;

  switch (changeType) {
    case "LOADED":
      component.set("v.isRecordLoaded", true);
      break;
  }
},
scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
  // parse record
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that there might be some better solution than this. But until now I did not find any better solution so marking yours as best :) Thanks!